# Parameter array type only receive the first element JSON Jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

This is my REST server and POST method. It has one query param which is an array of string

```
@POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public void create(
                @HeaderParam("authorization") String token,
                @QueryParam("title") String title, 
                @QueryParam("author") String author, 
                @QueryParam("path") String path, 
                @QueryParam("review") String review,
                @QueryParam("categories") List<String> categories
        ) {

                    System.out.println("title: " + title);
                    System.out.println("author: " + author);
                    System.out.println("path: " + path);
                    System.out.println("review: " + review);

                    for(String cat: categories) {
                        System.out.println("categories: " + categories);
                    }
    }
```

I try to post this json to the server using POSTMAN

```
{
    "title":"HP",
    "path":"D://image/hp.jpeg",
    "author":"JK",
    "review":"this book is great",
    "categories":["fiction", "horror","science"]
}
```

I expect I will receive an array of string which has 3 elements: fiction, horror, science but this is my output:

```
Info:   title: HP
Info:   author: JK
Info:   path: D://image/hp.jpeg
Info:   review: this book is great
Info:   categories: [fiction]
```

As you can see, my array has only one element which is the first element. 
Would you please point out what is wrong and how to fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set the queryparam with square brackets   @QueryParam("categories[]")